# Cannot connect to database from wpf outside development machine

Tags: sql, wpf, sql-server

I am currently creating a data drivien wpf application, and everything works perfectly as a charm on my development computer (the computer I used to create the program).  Also, when I move the app from the Release directory and copy to my local machine, it works perfectly.  But on the other hand, when my application reaches other users, it stops connecting to databases completely.

I don't get how this is as I have my connection string set properly, which is:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyConnectionStrint"
     connectionString="Data Source=MyServerIP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Which is an XML Config file located in the root directory.  As soon as the program is given to someone else, it stops functioning completely; no data is received or sent.

Could this be because of something like, they need MS SQL Server or something for it to connect to my remote database?  I even tried connecting to the database using SQL Server Management Studio, which fails to work on other PCS, but for some reason works on mine and no one else's.  This is a problem as this program is meant to be distributed to at least 15 people.  Any Ideas as to what Is causing this?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: My first guess is that there's a firewall blocking the SQL port, and only you and your dev machine are inside the firewall.  Can you check this?  (**or** is the IP a network-internal one like 192.x.x.x that only you can see?)

Comment: Hi there. no the IP is not internal, It is a remote server IP Address with SQL Server hosted on it. Im confused as to why it doesnt work as I have the exact same settings on my other machine as I do in my development machine.

Comment: Is the "t" in "MyConnectionStrint" in the actual config or is it just a typo in your post?

Comment: Oh sorry It was a typo, I meant connectionstrings

Comment: I don't understand from your question if the application runs correctly on any PC but only when you run it, or only on on some specific PCs regardless of who runs it. If it's the former, it's probably a permissions issue: you're using Windows authentication, so are the other users in the correct AD groups to have permission? If it's the latter, then there may be a component missing on those PCs. But in either case it's very likely that an error is being logged somewhere, either in your own application log or in the Windows event logs. Have you found anything?

Answer (score 0):

Is the database server on your development machine ?
If so, then you have to enable the tcp/ip configuration in your SQL Server Configuration Manager.
If that's not enabled then your server will not be accessible outside of the machine on which it resides.